# Running background service through shortcut

Tags: java, android, android-service

So I want to launch a service from a shortcut.  I know that this is not possible to do directly, so I've set up a activity with the sole purpose of starting the service.
The aim of my service is to send an intent to another app and then 5 seconds later send another so I've used a CountDownTimer to do this.
However, when I launch the Activity that starts the service from the shortcut (this is getting confusing) it launches the apps UI. I don't want this, as I want it to be a background service.
What am I doing wrong.  I've only just got into development, so it could be something obvious, but I've been battling with this for a few days now.

For some reason when I run it from the service it just launches the app straight away...
When I run it straight from the invisible activity it runs properly for the 1st 5 seconds fine and then loads the app...
I can't figure out why it's loading the app at all.

I've included as much info as I can that would be relevant.
Any help is appreciated!

My service:

```
    public class Pop1_5Service extends IntentService {

    public Pop1_5Service() {
        super("Pop1_5Service");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // Normally we would do some work here, like download a file.
        // For our sample, we just sleep for 5 seconds.
        new CountDownTimer(5000, 2500) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                Intent i = new Intent(INTENT_ACTION);
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putInt(BUNDLE_VERSION_CODE, 1);
                b.putString(BUNDLE_STRING_NAME, "POP1");
                b.putString(BUNDLE_STRING_VALUE, "1");
                i.putExtra(BUNDLE_NAME, b);
                sendBroadcast(i);           }
            public void onFinish() {
                Intent i = new Intent(INTENT_ACTION);
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putInt(BUNDLE_VERSION_CODE, 1);
                b.putString(BUNDLE_STRING_NAME, "POP1");
                b.putString(BUNDLE_STRING_VALUE, "1");
                i.putExtra(BUNDLE_NAME, b);
                sendBroadcast(i);           }
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

Activity that launches service:

```
public class Pop1_5Activity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Pop1_5Service.class);
        startService(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Subsection of Manifest:

```
<activity 
    android:name=".Pop1_5Activity"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<service android:name=".Pop1_5Service" />
```

And the 'Create a Shortcut' Activity:

```
public class CreateShortcutActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent shortcutintent = new Intent(this, Pop1_5Activity.class);
        ShortcutIconResource iconResource = Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(this, R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutintent);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "Pop1_5");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, iconResource);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the look of things, it looks like CreateShortcutActivity does nothing.
Your LAUNCHER is Pop1_5Activity, so when the user presses the app icon, this Activity will run, and it launches the Service.

All the code you have showed us are "invisible", the two Activities finish() themselves, and the Service is a Service.

You might want to look at how your BroadcastReceiver handles your broadcast. For instance, does it create another Activity through PendingIntent? Is the Activity created invisible?

Maybe you should try creating a pending Service instead of pending Activity in the BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
That is not the full Manifest. I have another launcher for the 'MainActivity' that launches the full app. I was under the impression from [this](http://kind-kristiansen.no/2010/android-adding-desktop-shortcut-support-to-your-app/) that I needed a separate activity to be called upon when the user wants to create a shortcut, and I added the intent-filters to the activity I want the shortcut to launch as it wouldn't launch without it...

Comment: May I suggest going about this differently?
**"So I want to launch a service from a shortcut."**
Your invisible Activity Pop1_5Activity (let's call this App1) is already a shortcut in itself, and it launches the Service that you want. You're set.

**"The aim of my service is to send an intent to another app"**
I think you are already doing this properly since you said that the app gets launched. If you are only sending information it would be better to process it in the BroadcastReceiver (maybe save it on SharedPreferences?) Don't do PendingIntent.getActivity().

Comment: Yeah, I think I need to start from scratch with this one, I think I'm going completely wrong. Thanks for taking the time to look at it though.

Comment: No worries. The link that you sent is useful for making a shortcut launch a different Activity other than your main (launcher) activity. As you know, Activities can be launched by other applications independent of the main one, as long as the exported property is set to true.